# how to look for the solution of complex problem?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic and satisfies the condition $|f(z)^2-1|=|f(z)-1|.|f(z)+1|\lt1$ on a non empty connected set open set U.

then

1) $f$ is constant

2) Imaginary part of $f$, im$f$ is positive on U

3) the real part of $f$, Re($f$) is non zero on U

4) Re($f$) is of fixed sign on U

how to look for this problem?

Comment: $f$ is analytic... but where? On which domain? Maybe the whole $\Bbb C$?

Comment: on U open set..

Answer (score 1):

The set $V:=\bigl\{w\in{\mathbb C}\>\bigm|\>|w-1|\cdot|w+1|<1\bigr\}$ is the union of  the two open blobs of a [lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate) $\infty$. From what we are told about $f$ we can only say that $f$ takes values in   one of these open blobs. It follows that 1) and 2) are false, and that 3) and 4) are true.

If you don't like lemniscates you can argue as follows: The set $V$ does not contain any point $iy$ on the imaginary axis, since for such a point one has $|iy-1|\cdot|iy+1|=1+y^2\geq1$. On the other hand $V$ contains neighborhoods
$$V_r:=\left\{w\>\biggm|\>|w-1|<{1\over3}\right\},\qquad V_l:=\left\{w\>\biggm|\>|w+1|<{1\over3}\right\}$$
of $1$ and $-1$: For a point $w\in V_r$ one has $$|w+1|\leq |w|+1\leq 1+{1\over3}+1<3$$
and therefore $|w-1|\cdot|w+1|<1$; and similarly for $w\in V_l$.

If $U$ is, e.g., bounded it is easy to produce a nonconstant $f: \>U\to{\mathbb C}$ that takes values in $V_r$, or an $f$ that takes values in $V_l$. But if $U={\mathbb C}$ then such an $f$ would have to be constant, by Liouville's theorem. In any case it is impossible to produce such an $f$ which takes values on both sides of the imaginary axis, since $U$ is connected.

Comment: is there any other way to do this?